# how to correctly output a List from data()? Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of links that I need to display. How do I write the correct code so that this list appears? In other words, it is necessary for information from this list to appear on the block

```
<div class="nav-dropdown">
  <span class="nav-title">
    <a href="">item 1</a>
  </span>
  <span class="nav-title">
    <a href="">item 2</a>
  </span>
  ...
</div>
```

Here is the code that I have, but I am doing something wrong because the list does not appear as needed.

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    'title': 'title 1',
                    'show': false,
                    'list': [
                        'item 1',
                        'item 2',
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'title': 'title 2',
                    'show': false,
                    'list': [
                        'item 1',
                        'item 2',
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      openItem(index) {
        this.items[index].show = !this.items[index].show
      },
    },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="(item, i)" :class="{show: item.show}">
      <div class="nav-title nav-title-caption" @click="openItem(i)">{{item.title}}</div>
      <div class="nav-dropdown">
        <span class="nav-title"><a href="">{{item.list}}</a></span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :class="{ show: item.show }">
            <div class="nav-title nav-title-caption" @click="openItem(i)">{{ item.title }}</div>
            <div class="nav-dropdown">
                <span class="nav-title" v-for="(listItem, index) in item.list" :key="index">
                    <a href="">{{ listItem }}</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'title 1',
                    show: false,
                    list: [
                       'item 1',
                       'item 2',
                    ]
                 },
                 {
                     title: 'title 2',
                     show: false,
                     list: [
                         'item 1',
                         'item 2',
                     ]
                },
           ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      openItem(index) {
          this.items[index].show = !this.items[index].show
      },
    },
}
</script>
```

In this correction, I've replaced `:key="(item, i)"` with `:key="i"`. Also, within the `nav-dropdown`, I've added another `v-for` loop to iterate over each item in the item.list array. Each list item is wrapped within an `<a>` tag for a link, as you have in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the items in the list to be displayed line by line, you need to add another **v-for** inside a span.

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="(item, index)" :class="{ show: item.show }">
      <div class="nav-title nav-title-caption" @click="openItem(index)">{{ item.title }}</div>
      <div class="nav-dropdown" v-if="item.show">
        <span class="nav-title" v-for="i in item.list" :key="i"
          ><a href="">{{ i }}</a></span
        >
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          title: "title 1",
          show: false,
          list: ["item 1", "item 2"],
        },
        {
          title: "title 2",
          show: false,
          list: ["item 1", "item 2"],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openItem(index) {
      this.items[index].show = !this.items[index].show;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```